# Change * in SELECT to show all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

Let's say I have a table with 100 fields, and I want to show 75 of them, how can I show all of the columns so then I can just comment out the ones I don't want? Basically de-nest the *...

Thanks!

Comment: Right-click table, Script Table as -> SELECT To -> New Query Editor Window. SSMS has no inline refactoring for this, as far as I know -- [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) does and it's pretty cool.

Comment: Cool trick in ssms. If you highlight click the database|table|columns node in the navigation treeview of any table and CTRL+C, the columns for that table are copied to you clipboard buffer as text.

Comment: if you work for a company and work with sql/ssms a lot, I would like to suggest sql redgate tools. They are totally worth the money, if the company is paying and you guys work with lots of sql queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the columns "folder" under the table in the object explorer and drag the folder to your query window. It will generate the entire list of columns with commas. Not nicely formatted since it drops all the columns on a single line but it works.

You could also use sys.columns to help. This would let you copy and paste the results into your query window.

```
select name + ', '
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('YourTableName')
```

There are also lots and lots of third party tools that can do this kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone! Everyone had great answers but I found the drag and drop solution by @SeanLange to be the one that's most up my alley. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

SSMS support GUI tool for it , but if you don't like GUI then you can use below script

```
declare 
    @table_name varchar(200) = 'Employees',
    @column_sql varchar(max) = 'select ';
select 
    @column_sql = @column_sql + 'T.[' + COLUMN_NAME  + '],'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME=@table_name;

select left(@column_sql,len(@column_sql)-1) + ' from ' + @table_name + ' T';
```

In NorthWind Employee Sample will get below result :

```
select 
T.[EmployeeID],T.[LastName],T.[FirstName],T.[Title],
T.[TitleOfCourtesy],T.[BirthDate],T.[HireDate],
T.[Address],T.[City],T.[Region],T.[PostalCode],
T.[Country],T.[HomePhone],T.[Extension],T.[Photo],
T.[Notes],T.[ReportsTo],T.[PhotoPath] 
from Employees T
```